# How to do math and combine data in datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have imported data from excel to data grid in w.p.f application and I am trying to do some math on the data and also combine some columns .Please advise as what would be the best way to handle this .

to solve this I was trying to create a C# class, but I do not know how to map or link my class objects to a column in data grid?

```
  class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

how can I map or link my C# class objects to a column in Data grid?

is it the easy way or I need to put everything into SQL database and write queries, I am good with SQL.
Any advise will be highly appreciated. I am trying to figure this out from a real long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by learning some basics regarding the `DataGrid`. This page should be helpful for what you're doing:
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/

You would define whatever columns you want to show in the `DataGrid` between the `<DataGrid.Columns>` tags. Each column has a `Binding` property which you use to set which property of your class (`Person`) is linked to that column via data bining.

As for doing math, you can create readonly properties for `Person`. Inside the readonly properties you could do calculations based on other properties and then return the result. To display the result, you would bind the readonly property to a column on the `DataGrid`. Keep in mind that if you the data in your `Person` class to be editable at runtime and have the math results update, you'll need to have `Person` implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged).

Answer (score 1):

You can always extend your Person class with extra properties that expose getter only with whatever combinations you want... Something like...

```
class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // added the = ""; just to prevent nulls 
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public string City { get; set; } = "";
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        // Now you can show these columns directly in the grid -- just an example
        public decimal MonthlySalary { get { return Math.Round(Salary / 12.0, 2 ); } }
        public string NameAndCity { get { return Name.Trim() + ",  " + City.Trim(); } }
    }
```